# Fetch frame count with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg

Does anyone know how to fetch the number of total frames from a video file using ffmpeg? The render output of ffmpeg shows the current frame and I need the frame count to calculate the progress in percent.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/84631/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-frames-in-a-video-on-the-linux-command-line

Answer (score 299):

## ffprobe

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_packets \
    -show_entries stream=nb_read_packets -of csv=p=0 input.mp4
```

This actually counts packets instead of frames but it is much faster. Result should be the same. If you want to verify by counting frames change `-count_packets` to `-count_frames` and `nb_read_packets` to `nb_read_frames`.

### What the ffprobe options mean

- `-v error` This hides "info" output (version info, etc) which makes parsing easier (but makes it harder if you ask for help since it hides important info).
- `-count_frames` Count the number of packets per stream and report it in the corresponding stream section.
- `-select_streams v:0` Select only the first video stream.
- `-show_entries stream=nb_read_packets` Show only the entry for `nb_read_frames`.
- `-of csv=p=0` sets the output formatting. In this case it hides the descriptions and only shows the value. See [FFprobe Writers](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#Writers) for info on other formats including JSON.

### Only counting keyframes

See [Checking keyframe interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18088156/)

### MP4 Edit List

The presence of an edit list in MP4/M4V/M4A/MOV can affect your frame count.

#### Also see

- [FFprobe Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html)
- [FFmpeg Wiki: FFprobe Tips](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips)

---

## mediainfo

The well known `mediainfo` tool can output the number of frames:

```
mediainfo --Output="Video;%FrameCount%" input.avi
```

---

## MP4Box

For MP4/M4V/M4A files.

`MP4Box` from gpac can show the number of frames:

```
MP4Box -info input.mp4
```

Refer to the `Media Info` line in the output for the video stream in question:

```
Media Info: Language "Undetermined (und)" - Type "vide:avc1" - 2525 samples
```

In this example the video stream has 2525 frames.

---

## boxdumper

For MP4/M4V/M4A/MOV files.

`boxdumper` is a simple tool from l-smash. It will output a large amount of information. Under the `stsz` sample size box section refer to `sample_count` for the number of frames. In this example the input has 1900 video frames:

```
boxdumper input.mp4
  ...
  [stsz: Sample Size Box]
    position = 342641
    size = 7620
    version = 0
    flags = 0x000000
    sample_size = 0 (variable)
    sample_count = 1900
```

- Be aware that a file may have more than one `stsz` atom.

Comment: Or, if you want more speed and if nb_frames is reliable enough, simplify as: `ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=nb_frames -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 input.mkv`

Comment: This outputs the answer twice for me (i.e. 2600 \n 2600). Any particular reason that would be happening?

Comment: @jbodily My example or juanitogan's? I can't duplicate it using either. Not much to work with here.

Comment: +1, not least because, unlike too many other answers about any command line tool, this one actually explains all the command line options. Thank you.

Comment: Note that the first option, query the container, actually processes the file due to count_frames. See @juanitogan's comment.

Comment: *This is a slow method. Because the whole file must be decoded* --> you're using `-c copy`, so no decoding.

Comment: *-skip_frame nokey* --> decoder option, so not used when copying.. `-discard nokey` is demuxer-level so decoding not needed but works only for formats with KF index in header (like MP4s).

Answer (score 35):

In Unix, this works like a charm:

```
ffmpeg -i 00000.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f null /dev/null 2>&1 \
                                          | grep 'frame=' | cut -f 2 -d ' '
```

Comment: Really a nice one. Just you don't need to copy the audio stream. You can use -an instat.

Comment: Allowing for a space after 'frame=' seems to at least improve constistency.

Comment: @PrakharMohanSrivastava Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28376817/2436175)

Comment: Actualy, this seems fast and reliable: `ffmpeg -i 00000.avi -map 0:v:0 -c copy -f null -y /dev/null 2>&1 | grep -Eo 'frame= *[0-9]+ *' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+' | tail -1`

Comment: @LloydMoore That's because *charms don't work*.  (Sorry, that expression *drives me nuts*)

Comment: @Michael thanks for the smile with my morning coffee :-)

Comment: @TimothyZorn You made my day!

Comment: What about on mac, for me I'm just getting blank, no output

Comment: +1 for redirecting stderr to stdout for grep. Would have saved me a lot of time googling if I'd just read a little farther down.

Answer (score 15):

## Calculate it based on time, instead.

That's what I do and it works great for me, and many others. First, find the length of the video in the below snippet:

```
Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 5994.00 
(5994/1) -> 29.97 (30000/1001)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/stu/Movies/District9.mov':
  Duration: 00:02:32.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9808 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264, yuv420p, 1920x1056, 29.97tbr, 2997tbn, 5994tbc
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16
    Stream #0.2(eng): Data: tmcd / 0x64636D74
```

You'll should be able to consistently and safely find       `Duration: hh:mm:ss.nn` to determine the source video clip size.  Then, for each update line (CR, no LF) you can parse the text for the current time mark it is at:

```
frame=   84 fps= 18 q=10.0 size=       5kB time=1.68 bitrate=  26.1kbits/s    
frame=   90 fps= 17 q=10.0 size=       6kB time=1.92 bitrate=  23.8kbits/s    
frame=   94 fps= 16 q=10.0 size=     232kB time=2.08 bitrate= 913.0kbits/s
```

Just be careful to not always expect perfect output from these status lines.  They can include error messages like here:

```
frame=   24 fps= 24 q=-1.0 size=       0kB time=1.42 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s    
frame=   41 fps= 26 q=-1.0 size=       0kB time=2.41 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s    
[h264 @ 0x1013000]Cannot parallelize deblocking type 1, decoding such frames in
sequential order
frame=   49 fps= 24 q=26.0 size=       4kB time=0.28 bitrate= 118.1kbits/s    
frame=   56 fps= 22 q=23.0 size=       4kB time=0.56 bitrate=  62.9kbits/s
```

Once you have the time, it is simple math: `time / duration * 100 = % done`.

Comment: Excuse me for being stupid but how can I do time / duration when duration is in hh:mm:ss.nn format and time is always xx.yy format?

Comment: @Omar, As a .NET dev, what I do is I create a `TimeSpan` from it, then use `currentDurationTimeSpan.Ticks / (totalDurationTimeSpan.Ticks / 100)`. The TimeSpan also provides a powerful Parse function, [check it out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/se73z7b9.aspx)

Comment: excellent solution, my time is in hh:mm:ss:ms so I suppose that in these 3 years FFMPEG improved the output time format.

Comment: Note that the console output may say 29.97, but that is short for 30000/1001. Same for 23.98 which is 24000/1001 and 59.94 is 60000/1001.

Comment: As a note, this doesn't work for variable framerate videos (obviously).

Comment: I'm trying to match a frame count from VirtualDub of 178253. 23.976fps 02:03:54.71 duration. I can get close but never exact! 178254.7852147852 is the closest I can make it. Anyone know how to get that frame count?

Answer (score 15):

You can use `ffprobe`  to get frame number with the following commands

1. first method

`ffprobe.exe -i video_name -print_format json -loglevel fatal -show_streams -count_frames -select_streams v`

which tell to print data in `json` format

`select_streams v` will tell `ffprobe` to just give us `video` stream data and if you remove it, it will give you `audio` information as well

and the output will be like

```
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "mpeg4",
            "codec_long_name": "MPEG-4 part 2",
            "profile": "Simple Profile",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "1/25",
            "codec_tag_string": "mp4v",
            "codec_tag": "0x7634706d",
            "width": 640,
            "height": 480,
            "coded_width": 640,
            "coded_height": 480,
            "has_b_frames": 1,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "4:3",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 1,
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "refs": 1,
            "quarter_sample": "0",
            "divx_packed": "0",
            "r_frame_rate": "10/1",
            "avg_frame_rate": "10/1",
            "time_base": "1/3000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0:00:00.000000",
            "duration_ts": 256500,
            "duration": "0:01:25.500000",
            "bit_rate": "261.816000 Kbit/s",
            "nb_frames": "855",
            "nb_read_frames": "855",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "creation_time": "2005-10-17 22:54:33",
                "language": "eng",
                "handler_name": "Apple Video Media Handler",
                "encoder": "3ivx D4 4.5.1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

2.
you can use

```
ffprobe -v error -show_format -show_streams video_name
```

which will give you stream data, if you want selected information like frame rate, use the following command

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=avg_frame_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 video_name
```

which give a number base on your video information, the problem is when you use this method, its possible you get a `N/A` as output.

for more information check this page [FFProbe Tips](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your first method seems the most convenient way to get all important info for all tracks (when leaving away `-select_streams`). +1

Answer (score 15):

Since my comment got a few upvotes, I figured I'd leave it as an answer:

```
ffmpeg -i 00000.avi -map 0:v:0 -c copy -f null -y /dev/null 2>&1 | grep -Eo 'frame= *[0-9]+ *' | grep -Eo '[0-9]+' | tail -1
```

This should be fast, since no encoding is being performed. `ffmpeg` will just demux the file and read (decode) the first video stream as quickly as possible. The first `grep` command will grab the text that shows the frame. The second `grep` command will grab just the number from that. The `tail` command will just show the final line (final frame count).

Answer (score 10):

Not all formats store their frame count or total duration - and even if they do, the file might be incomplete - so ffmpeg doesn't detect either of them accurately by default.

Instead, try seeking to the end of the file and read the time, then count the current time while you go.

Alternatively, you can try `AVFormatContext->nb_index_entries` or the detected duration, which should work on fine at least undamaged AVI/MOV, or the library FFMS2, which is probably too slow to bother with for a progress bar.

Answer (score 9):

Try something like:

```
ffmpeg -i "path to file" -f null /dev/null
```

It writes the frame number to stderr, so you can retrieve the last frame from this.

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
ffmpeg -i "path to file" -f null /dev/null 2>&1 | grep 'frame=' | cut -f 2 -d ' '
```

Comment: Doesn't work with the `*.ts`. The output is an empty line.

Answer (score 5):

Sorry for the necro answer, but maybe will need this (as I didn't found a solution for recent ffmpeg releases.

With ffmpeg 3.3.4 I found one can find with the following:

```
ffprobe -i video.mp4 -show_streams -hide_banner | grep "nb_frames"
```

At the end it will output frame count. It worked for me on videos with audio. It gives twice a "nb_frames" line, though, but the first line was the actual frame count on the videos I tested.

Comment: Thanks @acidrums4.  Verified this method works with the latest version from github I built today.

Comment: Worked for me using `ffprobe -i video.mp4 -show_streams -hide_banner | grep "nb_frames" | head -n1 | cut -d"=" -f2` which reduces the output to just the number.

Comment: Thanks, this works. If there is audio stream and video stream, then two numbers are displayed, one for audio and one for video

Answer (score 3):

The only accurate I've been able to do this is the following:

```
ffprobe -i my_video.mp4 -show_frames 2>&1|grep -c '^\[FRAME'
```

To make sure this works with video:

```
ffprobe -i my_video.mp4 -show_frames 2>&1 | grep -c media_type=video
```

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but that will only work if the video doesn't contain audio. If it does contain, this one will work: `ffprobe -i my_video.mp4 -show_frames 2>&1 | grep -c media_type=video`

Answer (score 2):

to build on stu's answer. here's how i found the frame rate for a video from my mobile phone. i ran the following command for a while. i let the frame count get up to about ~ 10,000 before i got impatient and hit ^C:

```
$ ffmpeg -i 2013-07-07\ 12.00.59.mp4 -f null /dev/null 2>&1
...
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[null @ 0x7fcc80836000] Encoder did not produce proper pts, making some up.
frame= 7989 fps= 92 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:04:26.30 bitrate=N/A dup=10 drop=0    
video:749kB audio:49828kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead -100.000042%
Received signal 2: terminating.
$
```

then, i grabbed two pieces of information from that line which starts with "frame=", the frame count, 7989, and the time, 00:04:26.30. You first need to convert the time into seconds and then divide the number of frames by seconds to get "frames per second".  "frames per second" is your frame rate.

```
$ bc -l
0*60*60 + 4*60 + 26.3
266.3

7989/(4*60+26.3)
30.00000000000000000000
$
```

the framerate for my video is 30 fps.

Answer (score 1):

I use the php_ffmpeg then I can get all the times and all the frames of an movie . As belows

```
$input_file='/home/strone/workspace/play/CI/abc.rmvb';
$ffmpegObj = new ffmpeg_movie($input_file);
echo $ffmpegObj->getDuration();
    echo $ffmpegObj->getFrameCount();
```

And then the detail is on the page.

http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/doc/api/ffmpeg_movie.php

Answer (score 1):

```
Cmd ->

ffprobe.exe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate,duration -of default=nw=1 "d:\movies\The.Matrix.1999.1080p.BrRip.x264.YIFY.dut.mp4"

Result ->

r_frame_rate=24000/1001
duration=8177.794625

Calculation ->

Frames=24000/1001*8177.794625=196071

Proof -> 

ffmpeg -i "d:\movies\The.Matrix.1999.1080p.BrRip.x264.YIFY.dut.mp4" -f null /dev/null
ffmpeg version N-92938-g0aaaca25e0-ffmpeg-windows-pacman Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --pkg-config=pkg-config --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-version=ffmpeg-windows-pacman --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --cross-prefix=/opt/sandbox/cross_compilers/mingw-w64-x86_64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32- --enable-libcaca --enable-gray --enable-libtesseract --enable-fontconfig --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libflite --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --enable-libmysofa --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenh264 --enable-liblensfun --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --extra-libs=-lm --extra-libs=-lpthread --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cflags=-DMODPLUG_STATIC --extra-cflags=-DCACA_STATIC --enable-amf --enable-libmfx --enable-gpl --enable-avisynth --enable-frei0r --enable-filter=frei0r --enable-librubberband --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libxavs --enable-avresample --extra-cflags='-march=core2' --extra-cflags=-O2 --enable-static --disable-shared --prefix=/opt/sandbox/cross_compilers/mingw-w64-x86_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32 --enable-nonfree --enable-decklink --enable-libfdk-aac
  libavutil      56. 25.100 / 56. 25.100
  libavcodec     58. 43.100 / 58. 43.100
  libavformat    58. 25.100 / 58. 25.100
  libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
  libavfilter     7. 47.100 /  7. 47.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'd:\movies\The.Matrix.1999.1080p.BrRip.x264.YIFY.dut.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.25.100
  Duration: 02:16:17.91, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2497 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 12:5], 2397 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 93 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Audio Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> wrapped_avframe (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, null, to '/dev/null':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.25.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: wrapped_avframe, yuv420p, 1920x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 12:5], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.43.100 wrapped_avframe
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : GPAC ISO Audio Handler
      encoder         : Lavc58.43.100 pcm_s16le
frame=196071 fps=331 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=02:16:17.90 bitrate=N/A speed=13.8x
video:102631kB audio:1408772kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
```

Comment: Framerate is normally calculated out of two parameters.
r_frame_rate=24000/1001 (=23,97602397602397...)

Rounded by ffmpeg to: 23.98 

Duration = hours*3600+minutes*60+seconds.remainder = 8177,91
While duration parameter = 8177.794625
But Frames=24000/1001*8177.794625=196071 gives exact number of frames.
(No kidding).

Answer (score 0):

*linux*

```
ffmpeg -i "/home/iorigins/Завантаження/123.mov" -f null /dev/null
```

*ruby*

```
result = `ffmpeg -i #{path} -f null - 2>&1`
r = result.match("frame=([0-9]+)")
p r[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `ffprobe` and `ffmpeg` info
is that the actual length in frames differs by some number.

This script tries to extract the last frames.
The frame number that succeeds works inside blender, too.
Frames beyond that number cannot be extracted in blender, neither.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# find the number of frames in a movie clip
FMAYBE=$(ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=nb_frames -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 $1)
let FMAYBE=$FMAYBE+1
FEMPTY="-"
while [ -n "$FEMPTY" ] ; do
  let FMAYBE=$FMAYBE-1
  echo "Trying $FMAYBE"
  FEMPTY=$(ffmpeg -i $1 -vf select="between(n\,$FMAYBE\,$FMAYBE)" -vsync 0 /tmp/fmaybe%d.png 2>&1 | grep 'empty')
done
echo "Succeeds: $FMAYBE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Get duration in seconds and multiply by frame rate. (This method is fast)

Get duration:

```
ffprobe -i input.mkv -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0"
```

Get frame rate:

```
ffprobe -v 0 -of csv="p=0" -select_streams V:0 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate input.mkv
```

If the answer has a fractional part then just truncate it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To count frames in ffmpeg you need to get the fps and duration of the file in seconds fps*duration=number of frames to get the duration and fps you can use ffprobe