# Dump last frame of video file using ffmpeg/mencoder/transcode et. al

Tags: ffmpeg, imagemagick, transcoding, mencoder, video-editing

I'd like to grab the *last* frame in a video (`.mpg`, `.avi`, whatever) and dump it into an image file (`.jpg`, `.png`, whatever). Toolchain is a modern Linux *command-line*, so things like `mencoder`, `transcode`, `ffmpeg` &c.

Cheers,
Bob.

Answer (score 24):

This isn't a complete solution, but it'll point you along the right path.

Use `ffprobe -show_streams IN.AVI` to get the number of frames in the video input.  Then

```
ffmpeg -i IN.AVI -vf "select='eq(n,LAST_FRAME_INDEX)'" -vframes 1 LAST_FRAME.PNG
```

where LAST_FRAME_INDEX is the number of frames less one (frames are zero-indexed), will output the last frame.

Comment: Thanks. Really helped me out there. I copied your commands without any changes.

Comment: I made a shell script out of these instructions.
https://gist.github.com/NelsonMinar/b00693feecc3b6673e36

Comment: Isn't this going to decode all frames, while seeking might be able to use key frames to skip a bunch of the video?

Answer (score 4):

I have a **mp4 / h264** matroska input video file. And none of the above solutions worked for me. (Although I sure they work for other file formats).

Combining [samrad's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28580469/3298637) and also [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28376817/3298637) and came up with [this working code](https://gist.github.com/sr9yar/05c371d813f834daf735b8365a267165):

```
input_fn='output.mp4'

image_fn='output.png'

rm -f $image_fn

frame_count=`ffprobe -v error -count_frames -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=nb_read_frames -of default=nokey=1:noprint_wrappers=1 $input_fn`

ffmpeg -i $input_fn -vf "select='eq(n,$frame_count-1)'" -vframes 1 "$image_fn" 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing I have not seen mentioned is that the expected frame count can be off if the file contains dupes. If your method of counting frames is causing your image extraction command to come back empty, this might be what is mucking it up.

I have developed a short script to work around this problem. It is posted [here](http://www.cvilleit.com/blog/-/blogs/scripting-extract-the-last-image-in-a-video-file).

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get Nelson's solution to work. This worked for me.
https://gist.github.com/samelie/32ecbdd99e07b9d8806f

**EDIT** (just in case the link disappears, here is the shellscript—bobbogo):

```
#!/bin/bash

fn="$1"
of=`echo $1 | sed s/mp4/jpg/`

lf=`ffprobe -show_streams "$fn" 2> /dev/null | grep nb_frames | head -1 | cut -d \= -f 2`
rm -f "$of"
let "lf = $lf - 1"
ffmpeg -i $fn -vf select=\'eq\(n,$lf\) -vframes 1 $of
```

Comment: No need for `grep`, `head`, or `cut`. [Just use `ffprobe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28376817/1109017).

Comment: Downvoted. If you're going to post a script that will delete the original video (without prompt!) for any non-mp4 despite the original question *specifically* listening two non-mp4 video formats, at least write a disclaimer. In bold. So you don't screw other people over.

Answer (score 1):

I found that I had to add `-vsycn 2` to get it to work reliably. Here's the full command I use:

```
ffmpeg -y -sseof -3 -i $file -vsync 2 -update 1 -vf scale=640:480 -q:v 1 /tmp/test.jpg
```

If you write to a NFS folder then the results will be very inconsistent. So I write to `/tmp` then copy the file once done. If it is not done, I do a `kill -9` on the process ID.

Comment: It works, but others should get rid of `scale=640:480`.