# Do not show Desktop between 2 videos

Tags: python-2.7, video, omxplayer

I´m working with OMXPlayer on Raspberry.
Right now I have a loop(with Python2.7) to show videos and it works correctly.
But I have two problems:
1. When one video is finished, the Desktop will be shown for one second. And I don't want it. How can I change quickly to another video without showing the Desktop?
2. Another problem is that I wanna show some pictures too.. I know that OMXPlayer does not show images... Can I use another program in my code? But the user should not notice the change.

Thanks.

Comment: set a blank png to desktop as background.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to figure this out too but I'm afraid it's not possible. It seams to me that omxplayer is only able to play a single video at a time and to play another video you have to run a new instance of the program. It takes a while to initialize, hence the gap between the videos.

That said, I figured a nasty way to get around it. When playing a video, you can [extract it's last frame into a PNG file with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8003411/1727370). Then, you can play the video with omxplayer and use whatever graphical tools you have to display the picture fullscreen in the background. When the video ends, it disappears but the picture stays there and since it's the last frame of the video, it appears to just freeze at the end for a second, before the next video starts. Then, you just repeat the process. Hope it helps.