# Extract the last frame of a batch of mp4 videos as a jpg

Tags: video, video-processing, video-capture

I have a folder of mp4 videos on **Windows 10**. I am trying to find a way to write a .bat file to spit out a jpeg of the last frame of all videos (there is over 100 videos)

I found vlc can dump a jpeg but it looks like it requires a timeindex and since each video ends at a different time this will not work. I couldnt find a "lastFrame" option in the vlc docs.

Is there anything else that can do this that is free? I was surprised to not see this requested that much in my yagooglizing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dump last frame of video file using ffmpeg/mencoder/transcode et. al](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248283/dump-last-frame-of-video-file-using-ffmpeg-mencoder-transcode-et-al)

Comment: Seems to be linux based as mentioned I need a windows solution. no accepted solution on this question and most answered is using a linux bash script.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract all the frames as PNG images and then delete every frame except the last one, extraction would look like:

```
ffmpeg -i video.webm Frame%04d.png
```

You would need to write your own script to look at the filename, find the one with the largest int value and then delete the others.

Comment: that would be an extremely intensive process considering some videos are half an hour to an hour long. I would like to just dump a single image rather than the entire contents