# Python: total number of video frames

Tags: python, video, pyffmpeg

I wish to use python to open a video file (avi, wmv, mp4), determine the total number of frames contained within the video, and save an arbitrary frame from within the video as an image file.

I have looked at pyffmpeg, but I do not know how to obtain the total number of frames contained in the video without iterating over each (which is **incredibly** slow). My code to obtain the number of frames in a video is given below:

```
import pyffmpeg
stream = pyffmpeg.VideoStream()
stream.open('video.avi')
frame_no = 0
# Very inefficient code:
while (stream.GetFramNo(frame_no)):
    frame_no=frame_no+1
```

Is there a way in which I can do this efficiently? If not, please suggest an alternative extension or approach; code fragments would be a nice bonus.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017843/fetch-frame-count-with-ffmpeg

Comment: No, the question you linked to relates directly to ffmpeg. I am trying to determine the number of frames programmatically using pyffmpeg.

Comment: Whoops, my bad. It looks liky pyffmpeg is a wrapper for ffmpeg? If so, the other post will probably tell you what to do.