# Extracting thumbnails from a video for creating sprite is really slow on large videos

Tags: ffmpeg

I have to create 'preview' on video progress hover. I'm doing with a sprite image and WebVTT file. Using `ffmpeg` and `imagemagick`. However generating thumbnails from a mp4 video is really damn slow (20-30 minutes for 2hrs and 20 min long video). The video is Full HD, H246 encoded, 2GB big. The command used

```
"ffmpeg.exe -i largevideo.mp4 -f image2 -bt 20M -vf fps=1/5 thumbs-%03d.jpg"
```

Which means thumb for every 5 secs of the video. Is there a way to make it faster? Videos in prod can be even bigger.

OS: Win10, ImageMagick is used later to create the sprite from all the thumbnails created with ffmpeg.

Comment: What is `$"` please? Which part uses **ImageMagick** please? What's a *"video progress hover"* please? What OS are you using please?

Comment: Did you notice I asked you to clarify 3 things?

Comment: Better now? Although I don't see how it would help.

Comment: No. It's still unclear what you are doing. If **ImageMagick** is taking all the time, you should be showing your **ImageMagick** code. If not, you shouldn't tag with **ImageMagick**.

Comment: Is is better now without the `imagemagick` tag? I think I've clearly mentioned that `ffmpeg` is the one which is slowing me down. This is the reason im showing the `ffmpeg` command.

Comment: Does it have to be every 5 seconds, or would key frames suffice?

Comment: No, it will depend on configuration, but I've also tested with 1 and 5 min and still takes 10+ minutes.

Comment: What I meant was do you require your screen shots to be taken once per 5 seconds, or can a somewhat arbitrary interval (with timestamps included) work for you? Note you can notify me of a reply with @llogan (I only saw your reply because the tab was still open).

Comment: @llogan interval is fine as well, as long as its faster.

Comment: You could *try* doing 2 halves, or 4 quarters, in parallel. Use `ffprobe` to get the length, then start two `ffmpeg` commands in parallel. The first will run from time=0 to time=total/2 and prepend output filenames with `A`, the second will start at time=t/2 and prepend output filenames with `B`.

Comment: I've created an online tool for this here https://davidclews.com/article/54.html which uses ffmpeg to create a webvtt and thumbnails that are contained in a zip file for download. If you would like the ffmpeg command you can look at the browsers console then copy and paste it from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Skip everything except keyframes:

```
ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i input.mp4 -vsync passthrough thumbs-%03d.jpg
```

Also see:

- [Get keyframe intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18088156/)
- [Control JPG quality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10234065/)

Comment: Well.. I think generating thumbnails based on keyframes only is more than enough for now. And x100 times faster. Thanks!

Comment: @Expressingx You could also use ffmpeg to make the sprite in the same command, but it's worth asking as a separate question (search first in case already asked and answered).

Comment: Oh really? That would make things simpler. Because I'm currently using `imagemagick` to resize the thumbnails, calculate grid size, create the sprite etc. And also using another lib, complicating deployment a bit more. I'll search a bit, if not I'll ask.

Comment: @Expressingx See [scale](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) and [tile](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tile) (or [xstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#xstack)) filters.

Comment: Nice `-vf "scale=100:60,tile=5x30"` thanks! However, now I don't know each thumbnail tile timestamp so I can generate proper `.vtt` file, but I'll have to figure it out I guess. I cannot tag you for some reason.

Comment: Okay, If someone needs it: `ffprobe -v error -skip_frame nokey -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time -select_streams v -of csv=p=0 input.mp4` this gives each keyframe timestampe in seconds. E.g. `8499.991500` which results to `02:21:39.9920000` in the format of: `hh:mm:ss`

Comment: @Expressingx Looks like you missed the [Get keyframe intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18088156/) link in my answer. You can use `scale=100:-1` or `scale=-1:60` to automatically calculate the other dimension while preserving aspect ratio.