# Video Keyframe and Iframe

Tags: ffmpeg, keyframe

I have confused one thing for Video Frame extraction.

I have [`sample.mp4` video](https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4), 15FPS.

I tried extracting Keyframe with FFMPEG.

```
ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i sample.mp4 -vsync 0 -frame_pts true out%d.png
```

I get 29 Pictures and I believe I have got 29 I frames. (If I have wrong, Please correct me)

Then I tried extracting specific timeline(10 sec) frame with picture

```
ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -ss 00:00:10 -frames:v 1 test1.png
```

This output picture, I can not find same one among my Keyframes I get.

Question: `test1.png`, What is frame type? Does it one of P or B frame not I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get 29 Pictures and I believe I have got 29 I frames. (If I have wrong, Please correct me)

Correct. See [Checking keyframe interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18088156/) to verify.

> Question: test1.png, What is frame type? Does it one of P or B frame not I ?

Use `ffprobe`:

```
ffprobe -select_streams v -show_entries "frame=pkt_pts_time,pict_type" -of csv input.mp4
```

Example output:

```
frame,9.968000,B
frame,10.010000,B <---
frame,10.052000,P
```

Note that in this example `-ss 00:00:10` rounded up to the nearest frame (10.010000). This is a B-frame in this example (`input.mp4`).

Comment: Thank you. I can get "frame,10.000000,P". It was "P" frame for my sampe.mp4.

Comment: Can I have one more question? With this ffprobe command,"ffprobe -v error -show_entries frame=pict_type,pkt_pts_time -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 -select_streams v:0 sample.mp4 > frames.txt", I can get frame type and its pts. However, It looks some of frame does not show frame type.

Comment: @SYMoon Use a pastebin site to show the output from ffprobe.

Comment: I realized I have missing "-select_streams v:0" parameter on ffprobe. Thank you.