# ffmpeg - how can I scale the video while perserving the total frames in it?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have a video with a size of `515 x 755`, that I would like to resize proportionally to `206 x 302` (so, factor is `2.5`).

In this video, I have the total of 588 frames, and I use `ffmpeg` to scale it, with this [command](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Scaling).

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf scale=206:-1 xRotation_206.mp4
```

And I use this to check how many frames are there in the video, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28376817/1627271).

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -map 0:v:0 -c copy -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/frame=/ {print $2}'
```

The original video frames is good (588 frames). But, after resizing with the command above, my converted video now has 604 frames.

The question is, **how can I resize the video by preserving the total frames in it?** It doesn't really have to be `ffmpeg` approach, and any suggestion is appreciated.

Here's the sample video that I use: [Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q9Wg6lNQS5haKSLfuL_TBZwbLd4z53eb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg, by default, generates constant frame-rate MP4s, so if your original video is variable-frame rate then ffmpeg will drop or duplicate frames to generate a constant frame rate output.

To avoid that, use

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf scale=206:-1 -vsync passthrough xRotation_206.mp4
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thank you.