# Merge two mkv videos in one but put theme in separate tracks

Tags: ffmpeg, mkv

I want to make a video player that displays more video streams at the same time using the mkv format.

I build my app so that when it decodes an Mkv video it puts all frames from a cluster in memory, from what I observe when I read a video with only one video stream, every cluster except the last one has equal numbers of frames.

I want to merge tow mkv files in one, but at the same time, I want every cluster from the video to have equal numbers of frames from both tracks.

Is this thing possible using FFmpeg or another tool?

Answer (score 1):

Use `-frames:v`:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.mkv -i input1.mkv -map 0 -map 1 -c copy -frames:v 100 output.mkv
```

To verify see [Fetch frame count with `ffmpeg`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28376817/1109017).