# Is ffmpeg giving incorrect frame count?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

The videos `Duration: 00:00:06.93` and `25 fps`
If we do the math it's 173.25 (173 rounded) frames.
However this command `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -qscale:v 1 filename_%06d.jpg` extracts 172 frames. Am I calculating or doing something wrong?
I want to use this of some automation in my Python project.

**Edit:**

I do have video frame in 6.840000

```
[FRAME]
media_type=video
stream_index=1
key_frame=0
pkt_pts=171000
pkt_pts_time=6.840000
pkt_dts=N/A
pkt_dts_time=N/A
best_effort_timestamp=171000
best_effort_timestamp_time=6.840000
pkt_duration=1000
pkt_duration_time=0.040000
pkt_pos=22689592
pkt_size=213060
width=1920
height=1080
pix_fmt=yuv420p
sample_aspect_ratio=N/A
pict_type=P
coded_picture_number=169
display_picture_number=0
interlaced_frame=0
top_field_first=0
repeat_pict=0
color_range=tv
color_space=bt709
color_primaries=bt709
color_transfer=bt709
chroma_location=left
[/FRAME]
```

My full frame dump [here](https://pastebin.com/du6PYKVc)

**Edit 2:**

My intention is to get the frames exactly, as when watching the video. I don't care about some frame being longer / shorter, audio longer etc. I tried to force the fps `ffmpeg -i LUCKY_BRUNETTE.mp4 -vf fps=25 -qscale:v 1 filename_%06d.jpg` but still got 172 frames.

Comment: @llogan `Option use_editlist not found`

Comment: `ffmpeg -i LUCKY_BRUNETTE.mp4 -use_editlist 0 -qscale:v 1 filename_%06d.jpg` this worked, but still 172

Comment: Sorry, typo. Should have been `-ignore_editlist 0`, so `ffmpeg -ignore_editlist 0 -i video.mp4 -qscale:v 1 filename_%06d.jpg`

Comment: Anyway, still 172 frames

Comment: @trshmanx What is your last frame's file name? Does video have sound (could sound track be 1 frame longer than video track)?

Comment: @trshmanx See [Fetch frame count with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28376817/).

Comment: @VC.One last frame name "filename_000172.jpg". Yes it has sound, how could I check is sound track is not longer?

Comment: Check out the updates in post