# Convert Python subprocess output from string to int or float

Tags: python, string, integer, subprocess, ffprobe

I am trying to read the frames of a video using [this command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28376817) but from a python script using the `subprocess` module. The output of the command is in `string` but since the frame count of a video is an integer I would like to have it as an `int` object in python. However, `int()` as shown [here](https://realpython.com/convert-python-string-to-int/#converting-a-python-string-to-an-int) is not working as expected for I assumed I would get `321` as an int.

Terminal Output:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I have tried solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10) like `float()` but they are not working for me.

Code:

```
import subprocess

def main():
    shell_ffprobe_frame_count = ["ffprobe", "-v", "error", "-select_streams", "v:0", "-count_packets",    "-show_entries", "stream=nb_read_packets", "-of", "csv=p=0", "test.mkv"]
    output = subprocess.Popen(shell_ffprobe_frame_count, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True)

    print(output.stdout.read()) # 321
    print(type(output.stdout.read())) # <class 'str'>

    print(int(output.stdout.read())) # should be '321'
    print(type(int(output.stdout.read()))) # should be 'int'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I got `<class 'str'>` as return type from the subprocess which I have never seen ever before. `type('321')` produces just `str` in my terminal. I do not understand the difference and I wager this is the reason for the error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The return value is *always* going to be a `str`. Further, `read` is destructive; you can't re-read the same value twice.

Comment: @chepner I understood my mistake. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first call to `output.stdout.read()` consumes all the output from the process; all subsequent reads return the empty string (indicating end of file). Slurp the output *once*, store it in a variable, and perform your tests on that stored string:

```
import subprocess

def main():
    shell_ffprobe_frame_count = ["ffprobe", "-v", "error", "-select_streams", "v:0", "-count_packets",    "-show_entries", "stream=nb_read_packets", "-of", "csv=p=0", "test.mkv"]
    output = subprocess.Popen(shell_ffprobe_frame_count, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True)

    outdata = output.stdout.read()
    print(outdata) # 321
    print(type(outdata)) # <class 'str'>

    print(int(outdata)) # should be 321
    print(type(int(outdata))) # should be 'int'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The `<class 'str'>` output is just how the `str` class itself is represented, it's what you should expect when printing the `type` of any `str` value.

Alternatively, since you seem to want to run the subprocess synchronously anyway, simplify things and [use `subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) instead (a synchronous, all-in-one wrapper for `Popen`), so it captures/caches the output for you:

```
import subprocess

def main():
    shell_ffprobe_frame_count = ["ffprobe", "-v", "error", "-select_streams", "v:0", "-count_packets",    "-show_entries", "stream=nb_read_packets", "-of", "csv=p=0", "test.mkv"]
    output = subprocess.run(shell_ffprobe_frame_count, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True)

    print(output.stdout) # 321
    print(type(output.stdout)) # <class 'str'>

    print(int(output.stdout)) # should be 321
    print(type(int(output.stdout))) # should be 'int'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which will also properly ensure the process completes and clean up allocated resources for it deterministically.

Answer (score 3):

When you call `read`, two things happened: it returns `'321'`, and it advances a pointer in the buffer providing the output. Calling `read` again doesn't re-read the last thing returned; it returns whatever is at the current position of that pointer.

Only your first call to `read` returned `'321'`. The second one also returned `''`, indicating the end of the stream, and the empty string is still a value of type `str`. The third call *also* returns `''`, which is not a valid argument to `int`.

You needed to *save* the return value if you want to use it again:

```
x = output.stdout.read()
print(type(x))  # <class 'str'>
print(int(x))  # 321
print(type(int(x)))  # <class 'int'>
```