# Melt framework - Add a background persisten between videos

Tags: mlt, melt-framework

I need to merge videos in a ratio of 16:9 with a png image to use instead of the black borders.
I'm running this command:
melt vid_1.mp4 vid_2.mp4 -mix 30 -mixer luma -consumer avformat:finish.mp4

I see the affine plugin but can make it work

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Maybe show a picture of what you want and what you are getting. Also, your command does not include any .png files.

Comment: @Brian i try to use a track for the background and another for the video compose like this:
melt -track bg.png in=0 out=500 -track v1.mp4 v2.mp4 -mix 30 -mixer luma -consumer avformat:finish8.mp4

Also try to make the compose in kdenlive and compare the xml to see if there is a clue o how to do it, i think it uses a producer with a qimage from here: 
https://www.mltframework.org/plugins/ProducerQimage/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
melt -profile atsc_1080p_25 bg.png -filter affine transition.rect="-36.8976 -58 1953.17 1300 1" -track v1.mp4 v2.mp4 -transition affine
```

This command will get you started. You will need to customize transition.rect to meet the needs of how you want to crop/fit your background image. If your background image aspect ratio matches your profile aspect ratio, then you can exclude transition.rect.

You should also change the profile to be whatever profile you want.

See the [melt documentation](https://www.mltframework.org/docs/melt/) for other helpful parameters (like in/out points)

See [Affine Filter](https://www.mltframework.org/plugins/FilterAffine/) and [Affine Transition](https://www.mltframework.org/plugins/TransitionAffine/) for details about the parameters for the image transformation.

Comment: Thank you, i try and it works fine in the screen, but it never ends.
I try to add a in and an out, and it works fine if i cut the first track before the composition ends
How can i make to run until the end of the join?

Comment: I can use this with ffprobe
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017843/fetch-frame-count-with-ffmpeg
and add to this command:
`melt -profile atsc_1080p_25 bg.png in=0 out=1203 -filter affine transition.rect=0 0 100% 100% 1 -track v1.mp4 v2.mp4 -transition affine -consumer avformat:finish2.mp4`